# Solve_IVP Precision

Tags: python, ode

Is there a way to increase the precision of the Solve_IVP parameters so that I can get a more accurate plot of the solution? Essentially, I am plotting the solutions to four different differential equations that each have a parameter k. I am finding sets of solutions for several k values (i.e. one iteration finds one set of equations, the next finds another set...) For each set I plotted the first function, and as of now I am getting the same plot (cannot tell difference between the graphs --- tried zooming in but that did not work). Is there any rule of thumb for deciding how precise we want Solve_IVP to be?

Comment: Usually integration is controlled in a way that the local error per unit step is about `max( atol, rtol*(norm(y)+norm(dy)) )`. Did you check that the 4 problems are actually different, that your different parameters are actually transferred to the ODE? Can you see a difference if the parameter sets are decidedly distant from each other?

Comment: @LutzLehmann What do you mean when you say "your different parameters are actually transferred to the ODE"? I called my parameters k, which is an array [k1, k2, k3, k4]. The differential equations are a function of k_i. For the first round, my for loop selected k1, then k2, then k3, then k4, and I printed them out during each iteration.

Comment: @LutzLehmann As you pointed out, I should have checked spacing. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try numerous things. Here are 3 (try from 1->3):

1. Increase the accuracy by passing the parameter 'max_step' and decreasing it. Try `max_step=0.02` and start lowering it to reach the desired accuracy.
   solve_ivp documentation: [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html)
2. Moreover, you can try different integration methods bypassing the parameter `method=`. As demonstrated by this [article](https://danielmuellerkomorowska.com/2021/02/16/differential-equations-with-scipy-odeint-or-solve_ivp/). `'LSODA'` offers the best accuracy.
3. Lastly, try the `dense_output=True` to continuously calculate all the points. However, this will increase the execution time as it takes more time to do so.

Comment: 3. should not be true in this generality, the interpolation function only needs not be computed if no `events` and `t_eval` are declared. The only difference in `dense_output` is that the data of each segment is assembled into one global interpolation function. So in principle there should be no time difference between passing `t_eval=t_sample` and getting the result in `res.y` or using the "dense output" option and evaluating as `y=res.sol(t_sample)`.